# Reproduce sharepoint file version history via rest api

Tags: rest, sharepoint

Is there a way to reproduce the information about the version history of a file in sharepoint via api, which information should I use?
When I follow this api
[image]

I get overwhelming xml with a lot of information, but is there some guidance which are selected specifically to show this:

[image]